# Jquery closest not working

Tags: jquery

I've trying for a while to now to figure out why I can never get the "closest" function from jquery to work.

Say I have this code;

```
<form>
<input type='text' name='q'>
<a href='javascript:void(0);' id='search_items'>Search</a>
</form>
```

Why does the following always alert "undefined"?

```
$("#search_items").bind('click', function () {
    var q = $(this).closest("input[name=q]").val();
    alert(q);
});
```

Thanks in advance!
Cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `input` element is a sibling, not an ancestor of `#search_items`. You want `siblings()` (or `prev()`, dependent on the flexibility required).

```
$("#search_items").bind('click', function () {
    var q = $(this).siblings("input[name='q']").val();
    alert(q);
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind that quotes are required in the attribute equals selector. So it should be `[name='q']`.

Comment: @Purmou: Only for string with spaces, AFAICT.

Comment: @Blender: ["Quotes are mandatory."](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: @Purmou: Documentation says so, but in practice, not. Still, I'd quote 'em. :)

Comment: @alex: Fair enough. :P Great answer, by the way!

Comment: @Purmou: Thanks, appreciate that.